# Python Multiline String Find

Tags: python

I have an Cisco ASA with a VPN tunnel configured.  I call the CLI command via API and it returns this multiline string:

```
\nSession Type: LAN-to-LAN\n\nConnection   : 192.168.1.10\nIndex        : 11701                  IP Addr      : 192.168.1.10\nProtocol     : IKEv2 IPsecOverNatT\nEncryption   : IKEv2: (1)AES256  IPsecOverNatT: (1)AES256\nHashing      : IKEv2: (1)SHA256  IPsecOverNatT: (1)SHA256\nBytes Tx     : 0                      Bytes Rx     : 0\nLogin Time   : 23:14:43 EST Fri Dec 3 2021\nDuration     : 0h:11m:50s\n\n
```

I can't figure out how to get only the "Bytes Rx" plus the number out beside it.  I've tried searching it like this, but it returns "Bytes Tx":

```
import re
regex_parse = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]\s+:\s[0-9]+')

multilinestring = webhook_api_call()
for item in multilinestring:
    a = regex_parse.search(item)
print(a.group(0))
```

Output:

```
Bytes Tx     : 0
```

I want to only get Bytes Rx and the number out beside it

Comment: Why are you doing `for item in multilinestring`? Is `multilinestring` actually a list or something? For the sake of example, forget about `webhook_api_call()` and just put in the string itself. For reference, see [mre].

Comment: Why aren't you searching for `Bytes Rx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to parse the result of `sh vpn-sessiondb l2l` from a Cisco ASA. The output is pretty standard, so I would skip the regex and do the following:

```
multilinestring = webhook_api_call()
lines = multilinestring.split("\n")
for l in lines:
    if l.find("Bytes Tx") != -1:
        print("Bytes Rx" + l.partition("Bytes Rx")[2])
```

**Output:**

```
Bytes Rx      : 0
```

Good luck with your code!

Comment: What about doing the whole line?

Comment: Just replace `print("Bytes Rx" + l.partition("Bytes Rx")[2])` with `print(l)`. With the `for` loop, you can print or search each line individually.